# Retrieve key from multidimensional object array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a multidimensional object/array and want to retrieve the value of the key labeled `confirm_enabled` and store it within a variable. Here is the object:

```
object(stdClass)#361 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["meta"]=> string(475) "{"feed_name":"Default Feed","auto_respond":"0","push_Salesforce":"0","lookup_enabled":"1","confirm_enabled":"1","voterdata_mapped_fields*":"9","voterdata_mapped_fields*":"10","voterdata_mapped_fields_*":"11","voterdata_mapped_fields_*":"","voterdata_mapped_fields_*":"","voterdata_mapped_fields_*":"13","voterdata_mapped_fields_*":"6"}" }
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What's the variable of these object array? Can you give me the line of code where you get these data's?

Comment: @aldrin27 The variable doesn't matter. I just need to know how to retrieve the value from the specified key.

Comment: how can i help you if you don't want to give me the code?

Comment: @aldrin27 But I did. I'd certainly appreciate your help, but I don't know what else I could give you. The data came from a field in a database. I just need to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! I'd forgotten to `json_decode()` before attempting to parse. I queried my database to retrieve the object, which is stored in `$meta`. From there, I just did the following:

```
$meta = json_decode( $meta[0]->meta );
$confirm_enabled = intval( $meta->confirm_enabled );
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$retrieve = (theVariable)->meta->confirm_enabled;
print_r($retrieve);
```

Or if you want to make all that an array use this:

```
$a =  json_encode((the_fetch_data)) // insert where you get the data
$b = json_decode($a) // then decode to make this all an array
print_r($b['meta']['confirm_enabled']); //show data
```